# What exactly will be rollbacked if a method annotated as @Transactional?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-transactions

In the example below, will `counter` be set to 0 if `persist(...)` will be rollbacked? Or only DB changes will rollbacked and `counter` remains 1? And what happens if I remove annotation for `myMethod()`?

Thanks and regards,
Andrej

```java
public class MyClass() {
   int counter = 0;

   @Transactional
   public myMethod() {
      counter = counter + 1;
      persist(counter);
   }

   @Transactional
   void persist(int counter) {
      jpaRepository.saveAndFlush(counter);
   }
}
```

Comment: The codes will not work and I guess it will throw exception . `jpaRepository.saveAndFlush()` can only apply to the `@Entity` but not `int`. I will be appreciated if you could revise your example to a valid one such that we can further discuss?

Comment: No, a rollback won't affect things in memory. You will either need to refresh from the database or have a method to catch the rollback and reset your counter

Comment: *What exactly will be rollbacked if a method annotated as* The transaction.

Comment: this might clear things up https://dzone.com/articles/how-does-spring-transactional